How diff a function W = f(x,y) w.r.t to a parameter that defines the trajectory gives the directional derivative of W in the direction of motion
This is about a derivation of directional vectors by parametrising position vector (r) w.r.t arclength (s) for a function W = f(x,y). the direction vector (u) has components <a,b>.
From what I understood r(position vector) has been parametrised with arc length (s) so that the component of r <x,y> can be given as relation of some c(initial point) + s*<a,b>. Now I understand that the position vector obtained will be in the direction of u as when s = 1 we move in the direction u from the initial point. Also from above both parametrised x(s) and y(s) have been obtained. But how this relates to dW/ds being the directional derivative in the direction of u (analogous to cutting a slice in the graph of W parallel to u at the initial point and getting the slope of the curve) is something I am not getting. dW/ds should be the rate of change of the function w.r.t arc length (s), not the directional derivative.

And what is the directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector $\langle a,b\rangle$?

@TedShifrin my intuition tells me it should be done by first getting components of i and j in the direction parallel and perpendicular to u <a,b> and then substituting it in the function W and differentiating w.r.t to that. This will give us the notion of change in the function for a small change in u direction. So something like dW/du.

Your intuition is far too complicated. Why would the function care what's happening perpendicular to the direction of interest? What is the definition of the directional derivative?

ok, i understand why the direction perpendicular to the direction of interest will not make sense. So will partial W/partial u be the correct one here? The definition would be the rate of change of function at the point in the direction of interest.

This notation is used in some texts. So, yes, with that definition, you look at the derivative of the function along the line through the point in the given direction, differentiating with respect to arclength (distance) along that line.
